# how to get th's value from td in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

My table design is as follows :

```
  <table>
      <thead>
         <tr><th class='fc-id1 ui-widget-header'>09:00</th></tr>
         <tr><th class='fc-id2 ui-widget-header'>09:30</th></tr>
         <tr><th class='fc-id3 ui-widget-header'>10:00</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr id='res1'><td class='fc-id4 ui-widget-content fc-resource1 '><div class=day-content'></div></td></tr>
          <tr id='res2'><td class='fc-id5 ui-widget-content fc-resource2 '><div class=day-content'></div></td></tr>
          <tr id='res3'><td class='fc-id6 ui-widget-content fc-resource3 '><div class=day-content'></div></td></tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Now on the page load i want to compare th's value with current time.
I have unique resourceid to compare with tr id and td class.

I am trying with this code. but its not working. Its giving null value.

```
  var td = $('.fc-resource'+ id); // this id will be the unique id coming from ajax.
  var th = td.closest('tbody').prev('thead').find('> tr > th:eq(' + td.index() + ')').html();
  alert(th);
```

can anyone help me please ?

Comment: wat is 'id' in first line and $d in second line....?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values?rq=1
Check this..

Comment: @sudhir: sorry its td instead of $d. and id will be the resourceid i.e 1 or 2 or 3.

Comment: Your html is bit odd. You have three rows of heading (each one cell). And then three rows of data (each one cell) displayed below all the heading rows.

Comment: It is jquery fullcalendar's resourceview's html. I need this code working for jquery fullcalendar only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just slight alteration to your code and it should work:

```
var td = $('.fc-resource'+ id); // this id will be the unique id coming from ajax.
var th = td.closest('tbody').prev('thead').find('> tr > th:eq(' + td.closest('tr').index() + ')').html();
alert(th);
```

Please note **`.closest('tr')`** before `.index()`

Here http://jsfiddle.net/RDZFU/ you can see that it works with html code you provided.

Comment: Are you sure that your html code looks exactly as you posted here? The code you posted seems to work properly with the code from my answer. Please check the js fiddle demo I provided.

Comment: ya i checked my html code also. It is jquery fullcalendar in which i need to use this.

Comment: hey I have updated my code in this fiddle. can you please check it ? http://jsfiddle.net/Zfym5/1/

Comment: @Mausami Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/Zfym5/2/ It will work and give you the content of the header right above the first cell you picked as `td`. Since all cells in your fiddle have same `.fc-resource...` class it will be the first one.

Comment: It is working. thanks kamil. but its giving me first th's value. how can i get all th's value so that i can compare it with give time value ?

Comment: No worries. I get it with td.each() function. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you just use

```
  var td = $('.fc-resource'+ id); 
  var head = td.parent().parent().parent().find("thead");
  var th = head.find("th:eq("+td.index()+")");
  alert(th.text());
```

Comment: but th has unique class which is fc-id1,fc-id2... you can use that

Comment: try this, i think this is what u want.

Comment: ya i also think so but its still displaying null.

Comment: can u make a fiddle of ur code? It ll be easier for me to know where is the bug.

Comment: It is a jquery fullcalendar's resource view page's html and i need this code to work with jquery fullcalendar.

Comment: how can i give you my code ? its too long. and i don't have login in fiddle.

Comment: hey I have updated my code in this fiddle. can you please check it ? http://jsfiddle.net/Zfym5/1/

Comment: Ok i found out one problem but i m not sure right now that which th exactly you want coz when u use var td = $('.fc-resourcemausami pandit'); will give u array of td. and instead of the above use this var td = $('.fc-resourcemausami.pandit'); this will give you an array of tds u can console.log(td) to see them.

Comment: ya i will try with td = $('.fc-resourcemausami');

Answer (score 1):

[**`Working FIDDLE Demo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/Zfym5/)

You get invalid `index` for your `td`. You must get `index` for it's parent `tr`. See:

```
var id = 2;
var td = $('.fc-resource' + id);
var tr = td.closest('tr');
var index = tr.index();
var th = td.closest('tbody').prev('thead').find('> tr > th:eq(' + index + ')').html();
alert(th);
```

Also don't forget check the [FIDDLE demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/Zfym5/).

Comment: thanks mojtaba. i also think so that this should work but its still displaying null.

Comment: Did you check the jsFiddle? I'm getting `09:30`.

Comment: I have updated my code in this fiddle. can you please check it ? http://jsfiddle.net/Zfym5/1/

Comment: @Mausami You have error in `HTML` markup. First, you have multiples `id` with same value. Second, your `id` has an `space`. `id="fc-resourcemausami pandit"`. It's invalid in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `eq()` method along with what was returned from the AJAX request. Add an `id` to your table for specificity:

```
var id = 1; //from AJAX
var th = $('#myTable th').eq($('.fc-resource'+id).index()).html();
alert(th);
```

Also, your markup is kind of messed up. You forgot to close some things up:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='fc-id1 ui-widget-header'>09:00</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class='fc-id2 ui-widget-header'>09:30</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class='fc-id3 ui-widget-header'>10:00</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id='res1'>
            <td class='fc-id4 ui-widget-content fc-resource1'>
                <div class='day-content '></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='res2 '>
            <td class='fc-id5 ui-widget-content fc-resource2 '>
                <div class='day-content'></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='res3'>
            <td class='fc-id6 ui-widget-content fc-resource3'>
                <div class='day-content'></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/aVFRV/1/)

Comment: but i have 2 more tables on the same page. will this each function work ? and yes i forgot to close some tags. thanks a lot.

Comment: and i need to get the th value whose td's class will match with the resource id. how can i get the th's value of a particular td whose class will match with the resourceid ?

Comment: @Mausami, I updated code and the jsFiddle. If that isn't what you want then I am completely lost

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('th').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var d = new Date();
    var text = $this.text();
    var parts = text.match(/(\d+):(\d+)/);
    if (parseInt(parts[1], 10) == d.getHours() && parseInt(parts[2], 10) == d.getMinutes()) {
        $this.addClass('now');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QZmc4/)

Comment: thanks arun. but i need to get the th value whose td's class will match with the resource id. how can i get the th's value of a particular td whose class will match with the resourceid ?